# Eleven Labs API not working, is ffmpeg not installed properly?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, artificial-intelligence

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danim\OneDrive\Desktop\programming\APItests.py", line 9, in <module>
    play(audio)
  File "C:\Users\danim\PycharmProjects\EXAM\venv\lib\site-packages\elevenlabs\utils.py", line 25, in play
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: ffplay from ffmpeg not found, necessary to play audio. On mac you can install it with 'brew install ffmpeg'. On linux and windows you can install it from https://ffmpeg.org/
```

I keep getting this error, and yes, I've gone to the web site and installed, made a path "C:\Users(my name)\ffmpeg\bin" and exported it there, but it doesn't work.

I'm expecting to get the result as audio from the free Eleven Labs API, but I keep getting these issues.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure you download ffmpeg-release-full to include tools like ffplay and ffprobe instead of just the essentials.
(You will see multiple versions to choose from after selecting windows builds on the [official download page](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows))

2. Make sure you have extracted it properly. Sometimes extracting can create another subfolder with the original compressed file name, depending how you do it.
3. You can verify whether ffmpeg and ffplay are correctly added to the path, open a new Command Prompt (to ensure it recognizes the updated PATH variable) and type:

   `ffmpeg -version` or `ffplay -version`

Comment: i did these steps and it still wont work, same error as before 

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ffmpeg-windows